# How should I updateOne a value inside an object inside an array?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I'm struggling with the syntaxis to updateOne a specified value inside an object inside an array.
This is my array of objects from my model

```
nombre:{type:String},
MaterialesProductos:[{Descripcion:{type:String},cantidad:{type:Number},codigo:{type:String},preciounitario:{type:Number},familia:{type:String}}]
```

This is how I insert values

```
await Producto.updateOne({nombre:req.body.ProductoAEditar}, { $push: {MaterialesProductos: {cantidad:req.body['MaterialesProductos[cantidad]'][a]}}});
```

But I would like to $set for example:
Producto.updateOne({"name:req.body.nameOfTheDocument", {InThisObject:{WhereCode:req.body.code},$set:{value:req.body.NewValue}});

```
await Producto.updateOne({nombre:req.body.ProductoAEditar},{MaterialesProductos:{codigo:req.body['MaterialesProductos[codigo]'][a]},$set: {cantidad:req.body['MaterialesProductos[cantidad]'][a]}});
```

This is how my data looks in my mongo atlas

```
nombre:"Aaron",
MaterialesProductos: Array
0:Object
Descripcion:
"Angulo 1/8" x 1 1/4" de 6.10 mts. (1.50 kg/mt)"
cantidad:0
codigo:"AA-03"
preciounitario:260.84
familia:"Aceros"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use `arrayfilters`:

```
db.collection.updateOne({
  nombre: "Aaron"
},
{
  $set: {
    "MaterialesProductos.$[item]": {
      Descripcion: "Angulo 1/8 x 1 1/4 de 6.10 mts. (1.50 kg/mt)",
      cantidad: 7,
      codigo: "AA-03",
      preciounitario: 460.84,
      familia: "Aceros"
    }
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "item.codigo": "AA-03"
    }
  ]
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/r8wDcRTgb8X)